# If I save variable in session scope, is it visible in application scope?

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee-8, application-scope

I did the following

```
getJspContext().setAttribute("authUser", user, PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);`
```

In my LoginServlet and the following

`User currentUser = (User) getJspContext().getAttribute("authUser", PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);`

In the other servlet. But `currentUser = null`, Only when I changed `APPLICATION_SCOPE` to `SESSION_SCOPE` it started to work.

**So, the question is, why application scope doesn't see the variable I set in session scope,** because in my opinion when I create variable in session scope, it is automatically becomes visible in application scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching attribute in a **specified scope only**, See [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-int-):

> Return the object associated with the name in the specified scope or null if not found.

To find in all scopes, use instead `findAttribute("authUser")`

> Searches for the named attribute in page, request, session (if valid), and application scope(s) in order and returns the value associated or null.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I just want to know whether the variable set in session scope will be automatically set and visible is application scope, because application scope is "bigger" scope than session one

Comment: @Donny Use instead `findAttribute("authUser")`

Comment: So, when variable is set in session scope it is NOT set automatically in application scope?

Comment: @Donny When set in session scope it is NOT set in application scope